# Where is Metadata stored which maps an Action Method to its View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I inherited a solution which has alot of old code and and I am trying to clean it up.

I know that the Convention is that the View will have the same name as the Action Method.

However,
When you right click in an Action Method and choose 'Add View' you can select a name for the View.  Is there somewhere where this relation is mapped or kept.

I know that 'by convention' the view engine will search for a view with the name under:

~/Views/ControllerName 
~/Views/Shared

but if you have given a view a name different than its Action Name how does MVC know to use that file, is there some data stored in the metadata of the method.

For example I have a

```
public class FooController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Bar() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

but when I right-click and 'Add View...'  I name the view Random.cshtml

How does this Controller Action method know to use this view.  Where is this data stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default view engine searches for a view with the same name of the action under ~/Views/[Controller]/[Action].cshtml

There is no metadata file or any sort of storage that contains the mappings.

You can write and inject your own view engine however, if you want to extend/change this behavior:

[MVC4 Razor Custom View Locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842638/mvc4-razor-custom-view-locator)

Comment: So where does the 'View name' that I type into the 'Add View...' dialog go.  When I execute the code in the example it selects my View.  The View is called Random.cshtml and no where in the Action method is that name specified.

Comment: What you are saying is false. I just created a new MVC 4 application, added a "FooController" with an action "Bar". I then added a view with "Add view", named it "Random" and tried it out. I get an exception saying "The view 'Bar' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."

There is more at play in your project if that works for you, because it shouldn't.

Comment: well I am on MVC but using .Net 4.0

Answer (score 1):

By default it will return the view with the same name as the Action, so in your case 'Bar'.

However, you can also specify a different view by name, like so:

```
return View("SomeViewOtherThanBar");
```

ETA: There is no mapping (that I know of) between a files/classes/etc. when you use the Visual Studio right-click helper to create views.

Comment: but when I leave the View name unspecified as in the code above it still calls the View I added thru the 'Add View...' dialog specifying the View name.